# a window is 'stuck'

Tags: windows-7, freeze

I am using windows 7 but i am positive it happens in XP. This only happened to be once on XP and once on windows 7. I have an app, i can open it however it does not show up. I can tell its running in the background and running properly however i cant make the GUI show. Its like its permanently hidden. I killed the process and tried opening it however it still hidden away.

How do i fix this? BTW this current app the GUI isnt listed in the application tab in task manager. When i had another app stuck in windows XP i had to reinstall it to fix it.

-edit- i fixed the problem. It still isnt shown in the task bar even tho i can see it. Solution: Put your mouse over the window tab and a little window will pop up to show how the app looks like. Move your mouse over it, right click and hit maximize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why Tslib's answer is set to deleted, it is one thing I would of suggested.. it could be hidden off screen - on Windows 7, press <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> a couple of times as this should be able to maximise an on screen object to full screen.

If this doesn't work, it could just be the application that is bad, try doing a reinstall, but it would help if you told us what it is.

Any more help would really be dependent on the application.

Comment: Good tip. The app ignores those keys >_>. However the rest of the programs i tried does not.

Answer (score 0):

If the application isn't listed in the applications tab of Task Manager, that means it never succeeded in creating a main window. If you're comfortable editing the registry, you might look for the part of the registry that holds the program configuration and delete it.